# Font Google Montserrat not loaded in vaadin created by https://start.vaadin.com/app/p

Tags: vaadin-flow

I create vaadin 24 flow with https://start.vaadin.com/app/p .
I chose Montserrat as font theme, Vaadin 24.x and Java 17. It is displayed in [image: apps_with_montserrat]

While apps is running, it doesn't use Montserrat but default font. It is shown below [image: app_with_default]

Montserrat is font from google font that should be downloaded automatically from google, if i am not mistaken.

How can I fix this problem?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. I install *Montseratt* using

> npm install @fontsource/montserrat`
> 2. Run application with profile Production (with green run button) or
> mvn clean package -Pproduction java -jar target/package.jar